Curvature of the hermitian connection
Let $(M,g)$ be a hermitian manifold and consider the hermitian connection on $TM$. If we look at the curvature $R$ given by this connection, I wanted to know if its an element of $\mathcal{A}^{1,1}(\text{End}(T^{1,0}M))$ or just $\mathcal{A}^{1,1}(\text{End}(TM))$?
I think that the latter holds by definition, but is it in $\mathcal{A}^{1,1}(\text{End}(T^{1,0}M))$ or only in $\mathcal{A}^{1,1}(\text{End}(TM))$? Also I may be making a mistake by thinking that $R$ is a $2$-form with values in $TM$ instead of the complexified bundle so let me know if I'm wrong.

Isn't your hermitian metric only on the holomorphic tangent bundle?

What do you mean by the hermitian connection?
